# Single out part of string in Python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to detect if `http://` or `https://` is in a variable string or not.
For example: `http://google.com` or `https://google.com`
While technically my code works, since it's all one word, it actually bypasses my code thinking that `http://` or `https://` isn't present in the string.

Is there a way to single out part of the string e.g., find `http://` or `https://` in a one-word string?

Code is attached - `barcode_info` currently contains `"http://google.com"` so it should bypass this part since the code is seeing if http:// or https:// is NOT contained in the string.

```py
if "http://" or "https://" not in barcode_info:
    print("This QR Code doesn't contain a URL link. Would you still like to view the QR contents? \n")
    qr_Opt = input("1. Yes \n 2. No \n")
    if qr_Opt == "1":
        print("How would you like to view QR contents? \n")
        view_Opt = input("1. View in CLI \n2. Output to txt file \n3. View in CLI + txt file\n")
    if view_Opt == "1":
        print(barcode_info)
        quit()
    elif view_Opt == "2":
        file.write(barcode_info)
        quit()
    elif view_Opt == "3":
        print(barcode_info)
        file.write(barcode_info)
        quit()
    else:
        print("Invalid option. Quitting.")
        quit()
```

Comment: I think `if "http://" or "https://" not in barcode_info:` should be `if "http:// not in barcode_info and "https://" not in barcode_info`. The way you have it, with `"http://" or "https://"`, the `or` statement will return `"http://"`, so your statement is equivalent to `if "http://" not in barcode_info:`, I believe.

Comment: That's not how `or` works: `if "http://" or "https://" not in barcode_info` is always `True` because `"http://"` is truthy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've changed "or" to "and" but still get the same issue.

Comment: "I've changed "or" to "and" but still get the same issue." Please re-read the comment more carefully. You must change more than that.